# What mount system is this Raynox lens?

Tags: lens-mount, equipment-identification, raynox

This lens says "Raynox Tele Auto MC 3.5 200mm" - any idea what mount it could be?

[image: barrel]
[image: back]
[image: front]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be the Minolta MC/MD mount. The giveaway is the aperture actuation lug inside the bayonet mount, and the notch in one of the bayonet tabs opposite the aperture lug, at the upper-left position of the bayonet ring in your 2nd photo.

Note, that "MC" probably doesn't mean MC mount in this case. It probably means "multi-coated".

Reference: [Rick Oleson's lens mount identification page](http://rick_oleson.tripod.com/index-99.html)

Comment: I also thought it looked like a Minolta, so much so that I tried to put it on my Minolta Dynax 500si. But I guess that camera is AF mount and thus will not take MC/MD mount?

Comment: No it did not fit...

Comment: Just to clarify, Minolta AF mount (which is what Sony calls A mount after they bought Minolta) is not the same as Minolta's old MC/MD/SR mounts

Comment: You can however buy adapters really cheaply

Comment: I have a Minolta XD-7 now, it does fit on that. :-)